# CGContextClearRect causing background color to be black

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, core-graphics

I have a `UIButton` subclass that I am drawing borders on using `drawRect:`. When the button is selected I want the background color to change, and the borders removed. (Drawing borders manually because sometimes I only need one border on one side)

For some reason when I use `CGContextClearRect` to remove the borders that have already been drawn I get a black background instead of the color that I set:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];

    if (selected) {
        self.allOff = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = self.selectedColor;
        [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    } else {
        self.allOff = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = self.defaultColor;
        [self setTitleColor:[OTAColors colorWithRed:163 green:163 blue:163] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}

- (void)_setup {

    self.opaque = NO;

    self.defaultColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.99];
    self.selectedColor = [[OTAColors colorWithRed:33 green:59 blue:70] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.99];

    self.backgroundColor = self.defaultColor;
    [self setTitleColor:[OTAColors colorWithRed:163 green:163 blue:163] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:OTAFontPFDinTextCondProMedium size:20];
    self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGFloat borderWidth = 0.7f;
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, borderWidth);
    UIColor *borderColor = self.borderColor ? self.borderColor : [UIColor blackColor];
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, borderColor.CGColor);

    if (!self.allOff) {
        // Left
        if (self.left) {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 0);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 0,rect.size.height);
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
        }

        // Right
        if (self.right) {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width, 0);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
        }

        // Top
        if (self.top) {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 0);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width,0);
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
        }

        // Bottom
        if (self.bottom) {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, rect.size.height);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
        }
    } else {
        CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);
    }

}
```

Any ideas why this would be happening? `CGContextClearRect` seems to be causing this issue.

Comment: Why aren't you drawing the background in draw rect?

Comment: @Wain - I guess because I added the drawing code quite a while later, so I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling clear rect clears everything, so it reverts to the default black content. Instead you should fill the rect with the background colour first and then draw the appropriate lines for the borders after that.